# aglio API blueprint render installing error

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, centos, npm, aglio

I am trying to install aglio, https://github.com/danielgtaylor/aglio and unable to proceed forward due to an error i am getting.

```
npm ERR! Failed at the protagonist@0.17.1 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
```

My server is cento OS 6.5,

I installed node js as explained here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-run-a-node-js-app-on-centos-6-4-64bit

And then it showed another error as coffee script 1.8.0 is not found. the i installed it as `npm install -g coffee-script`

so please suggest me how to get rid of this error.

This is the full information about the error.

```
[root@hellop ~]# npm install -g aglio
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@0.3.1

> ws@0.5.0 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/aglio/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

^C[root@hellop ~]# npm install aglio
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@0.3.1

> ws@0.5.0 install /root/node_modules/aglio/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

make: Entering directory `/root/node_modules/aglio/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil.node: Finished
  COPY Release/bufferutil.node
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/validation.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/validation.node: Finished
  COPY Release/validation.node
make: Leaving directory `/root/node_modules/aglio/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws/build'

> ws@0.4.31 install /root/node_modules/aglio/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/ws
> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

make: Entering directory `/root/node_modules/aglio/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/ws/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil.node: Finished
  COPY Release/bufferutil.node
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/validation/src/validation.o
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/validation.node
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/validation.node: Finished
  COPY Release/validation.node
make: Leaving directory `/root/node_modules/aglio/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/ws/build'

> protagonist@0.17.1 install /root/node_modules/aglio/node_modules/protagonist
> node-gyp rebuild

make: Entering directory `/root/node_modules/aglio/node_modules/protagonist/build'
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/libsnowcrash/snowcrash/src/CBlueprint.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/libsnowcrash/snowcrash/src/CBlueprintSourcemap.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/libsnowcrash/snowcrash/src/CSourceAnnotation.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/libsnowcrash/snowcrash/src/HTTP.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/libsnowcrash/snowcrash/src/Section.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/libsnowcrash/snowcrash/src/Serialize.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/libsnowcrash/snowcrash/src/SerializeJSON.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/libsnowcrash/snowcrash/src/SerializeYAML.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/libsnowcrash/snowcrash/src/Signature.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/libsnowcrash/snowcrash/src/snowcrash.o
g++: Internal error: Killed (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report.
See <http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla> for instructions.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/libsnowcrash/snowcrash/src/snowcrash.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/root/node_modules/aglio/node_modules/protagonist/build'
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:267:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:784:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-431.20.3.el6.x86_64
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /root/node_modules/aglio/node_modules/protagonist
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Linux 2.6.32-431.20.3.el6.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "aglio"
npm ERR! node v0.10.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.1.16
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! protagonist@0.17.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the protagonist@0.17.1 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the protagonist package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls protagonist
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /root/npm-debug.log
[root@hellop ~]# npm install protagonist
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two different problems here.

One is that you are using quite an old `node` and `npm`.  The digital ocean guide you are following is a bit out of date.  Instead of building your own `node` version 0.10.4, you should update to a new packaged node 0.10.35 by following the guide here: https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#usage-instructions-1

`sudo -s
curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup | bash -
yum install -y nodejs
yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'
ctrl+D`

Then update to the latest `npm`

`sudo npm install -g npm@latest`

That will fix your first problem, an out-of-date `node` and `npm`.  Now on to your second problem, which is that you can't build `protagonist`.  You are running into an internal compiler error:

`CXX(target) Release/obj.target/libsnowcrash/snowcrash/src/snowcrash.o
g++: Internal error: Killed (program cc1plus)
Please submit a full bug report.
See <http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla> for instructions.
make: *** [Release/obj.target/libsnowcrash/snowcrash/src/snowcrash.o] Error 1`

If this persists even after you have updated `node` and `npm`, then the most likely causes are a hardware error, a corrupt compiler or utility, or a very serious problem in the `protagonist` package.  Please let me know, and I will try to help you troubleshoot it further.